# Django Server Just Stops

Tags: python, django

I just got done upgrading to Django 2.2.3 from version 2.0.

For some reason the system will just stop working when going to a new page.  I might go one or to pages and then the server stops.

I am also using Cookiecutter.

Below is a typical message that I am receiving.  Though it changes.

it was acting strange before this - why I upgraded.

I checked all my migrations.  Reinstalled Django.  Using Pycharm.

Thanks.

```
[17/Jul/2019 08:26:04] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13126
[17/Jul/2019 08:26:04] "GET /static/CACHE/css/app.8e450f098f62.css HTTP/1.1" 200 323872
AttributeError: cffi library '_ffi' has no function, constant or global variable named '__spec__'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 275, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 281, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 321, in tick
    state.update(self.loop_files(state, previous_timestamp))
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 328, in loop_files
    for path, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 348, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 241, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "/Users/benson/PycharmProjects/myanalysis/v_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 114, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not isinstance(module, ModuleType) or getattr(module, '__spec__', None) is None:
SystemError: <built-in function getattr> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: That looks like a bug in the `py` package (which usually gets installed as a dependency of `pytest`). Try upgrading it (`pip install -U py`).

Comment: I tried that but did not kill the gremlins.  I tried a different version of Django and got the above error. (I edited it from previous error.)

Comment: At this point I'd suggest nuking the entire venv and recreating it, just to be sure there's no weirdness going on in the libraries.

Comment: I did a complete reinstall and things seem to be ok.  thanks.